# ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object - trying to do a register on database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to do a "livros" register with a foreign key from user, but when i try to send the information to database this error appear "ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object" could someone help me?

LIVROCONTROLLER

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Livro;

class LivroController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    protected $request;
    private $repository;
    private $livro;

    public function __construct(Livro $livro)
    {
        $this->livro = $livro;
    }
        
    
    
    public function index()
    {
       /* $title = 'listagem dos livros';
        $livros = $this->livro->all();
        return view ('livros/cadastro', compact('livros','title'));*/
        return view ('livros/cadastro');
    }

    protected function validator(Request $request)
    {
        return Validator::make($request, [
            'namel' => ['required', 'string', 'max:200'],
            'autor' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:200'],
            'editora' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'categoria'=> ['required', 'string', 'min:50'],
            'classificação'=> ['required', 'string', 'min:1','max:2'],
            'descricao'=> ['required', 'string', 'min:200'],
            'image'=> ['not required'],
  
        ]);
    }

     /**
      * Store a newly created resource in storage.
      *
      * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        
        $user = Auth::user()->id;
        Livro::create([
            'users_id' => $user,
            'namel' => $request['namel'],
            'autor' => $request['autor'],
            'editora' => $request['editora'],
            'categoria'=> $request['categoria'],
            'classificação'=>$request['classificação'] ,
            'descricao'=>$request['descricao'],
            'image'=>$request['image'],
        ]);
        return view('livros/cadastro');
    }

    
    

}
```

LIVROS MIGRATION TABLE

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLivrosTable extends Migration
{
        /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('livros', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
 
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            /*Auth::user()->id;*/

            $table->text('namel');
            $table->string('autor');
            $table->string('editora');
            $table->string('categoria');
            $table->string('classificação');
            $table->text('descricao');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();


        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('livros');
    }
}
```

LIVRO BLADE FILE

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card" >
            <br>
            <div class="textocs">
               <h4>CADASTRO DE LIVROS</h4>

               </div>
<br><br>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" enctype=”multipart/form-data” action="{{ url('/cadastro_livros') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="namel" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nome') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="namel" type="text" class="form-control @error('namel') is-invalid @enderror" name="namel" value="{{ old('namel') }}" required autocomplete="namel" autofocus>

                                @error('namel')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="autor" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Autor') }}</label>
                           
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="autor" type="text" class="form-control @error('autor') is-invalid @enderror" name="autor" value="{{ old('autor') }}" required autocomplete="autor">

                                @error('autor')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="editora" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('editora') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="editora" type="text" class="form-control @error('editora') is-invalid @enderror" name="editora" value="{{ old('editora') }}" required autocomplete="editora" autofocus>

                                @error('editora')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror 

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="categoria" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('categoria') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="categoria" type="text" class="form-control @error('categoria') is-invalid @enderror" name="categoria" value="{{ old('categoria') }}" required autocomplete="categoria" autofocus>

                                @error('categoria')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="classificação" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('classificação (1-10)') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="classificação" type="number" maxlength="2" class="form-control @error('classificação') is-invalid @enderror" name="classificação" value="{{ old('classificação') }}" required autocomplete="classificação" autofocus>

                                @error('classificação')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror 

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="descricao" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('descricao') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="descricao" type="text" class="form-control @error('descricao') is-invalid @enderror" name="descricao" value="{{ old('descricao') }}" required autocomplete="descricao" autofocus>

                                @error('descricao')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror 

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('imagem') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" name="image" value="{{ old('image') }}" required autocomplete="image" autofocus>

                                @error('image')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        

                        <br><br>
                        
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Cadastrar') }}
                                </button>
                           


                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

ROUTE TO THE REGISTER "LIVROS"

```
Route::get('/cad_livros', [App\Http\Controllers\LivroController::class, 'index']); 
Route::post('/cadastro_livros',[App\Http\Controllers\LivroController::class, 'create']);
```

Comment: If `Auth::user()` returns `NULL` and it tries to get `id` from NULL hence the error. If you are not logged in, then it will throw a null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not logged-in and inside your `create` method you are trying to get the `id` of `Auth::user()` which is `null`, so you get that error.

If this `create` requires the user to login, protect your route with `auth` middleware.

```php
Route::post(
    '/cadastro_livros',
    [App\Http\Controllers\LivroController::class, 'create']
)->middleware('auth');
```